# Do you need a Fortran compiler in your machine to have Matlab work?

Tags: matlab, fortran, lapack

Do you need a Fortran compiler in your machine to have Matlab work?

I read that "Linear algebra functions and matrix operations in MATLAB® are built on LAPACK," and also learned that LAPACK is written in Fortran 90, so I guess we would need to have a Fortran compiler in our machine to make Matlab work. However, I was using Matlab some time ago without having a Fortran compiler installed. So I am a bit confused.

Comment: Those nice folk at the MathWorks have compiled the Fortran sources (if they use any) for you and bundled them into Matlab so you don't have to.  If you should take it into your head to write code in Fortran to link into Matlab (perhaps using MEX files) why then, yes, you would need a Fortran compiler.

Comment: Most ordinary people do not have any compiler on their computers or phones and still use a lot of software written in various programming languages and using various libraries. There are often redistributable libraries available with compilers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. The Matlab executable(s) are compiled from various sources, some of which may be fortran or derived from fortran code. But whether that's the case or not, it doesn't matter to the Matlab user. Matlab is delivered as a ready-to-run program.

For complete requirements necessary to run Matlab, see
https://www.mathworks.com/support/requirements/matlab-system-requirements.html